# How can I use ajax to call a PayPal (cross-domain) URL on a shared server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal

Before invoking a PayPal transaction, I need to do some DB work. I cannot use any inline on-click or -submit on the PayPal form since these events will not fire. Instead, I created a click event.

All goes well until I try to post the PayPal URL and then I receive the following message:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?callback=jQuery21305853672787723263_1470402669954'
>   because its MIME type  ('text/html') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          contentType: 'application/javascript
      }
      ...
```

Another SO answer suggested the content-type needs to be changed to 'application/javascript on the server, but this cannot be done on my shared server.

Any ideas on a work-around are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of PayPal integration is it? Can you do anything server side?

Comment: Express checkout. I am also integrating the notification API, which I call before posting the URL in question. Thanks for this suggestion. I will try using PHP to redirect the URL. I'll let you now how it goes.

Comment: Within the Notification IPN, I issued: header('location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); but it did not invoke the PayPal verify transaction forms and I received an IPN FAILURE report.

Comment: In Express checkout you redirect to the payment gateway - so there's really no need to do an ajax request (afaik). **If** you really have to request a resource from external server you can do a cURL request (for example -  $.ajax request to /paypal-request/ causes cURL to be called, with the parameters that you provide by GET) - this way you can get around your issue, as you won't be using `jsonp` at all. IPNs are retrieved server side as well

Comment: I do not have to use $.ajax to invoke EC. Can I just use a PHP post to?  I am a little new to cURL. I (and others) would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/ - the way EC works is that you create a `form` that POSTs data to payment gateway. For each item / line in your order you create an `input` element. Then you just submit that `form`.